# CALayer: Linear Gradient Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, linear-gradients

I am drawing a Linear Gradient on one of my CALayers with some colors, but randomly, with the same input, the colors are drawn on the screen as a pink color.

The code is as follows:

```
bottomComponents = bottomColor.colorComponents;
topComponents = topColor.colorComponents;
middleComponents = middleColor.colorComponents;

CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGGradientRef glossGradient;
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;

size_t numberOfLocations = 3;
CGFloat locations[3] = {0.0f, MIDDLE_POINT, 1.0f};
CGFloat components[12] =
{
    topComponents.red, topComponents.green, topComponents.blue, topComponents.alpha,
    middleComponents.red, middleComponents.green, middleComponents.blue, middleComponents.alpha,
    bottomComponents.red, bottomComponents.green, bottomComponents.blue, bottomComponents.alpha
};

rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, numberOfLocations);

CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
CGPoint bottomCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetHeight(currentBounds));
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, bottomCenter, 0);

CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);
```

Where `colorComponents` is just returning a struct with the color components.

When I output the color in a log, it is the proper color, but when it shows up on screen, regardless of the start colors, it is a pink-ish color.

Is there anything that I have done wrong that could cause the random pink to show up?

The pink shows up completely sporadically. I will load from the exact same values and rarely, but surely, it will show up pink. Loading from different values yields the same results. Its happening around 1-2% of the time.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are you passing the color values as full RGBA or are you using the UIColor class methods for predefined values?

Comment: @Lefteris I'm passing them as full RGBA. That sucks, then. For once, I was hoping I was wrong..

Comment: Are you experiencing the issue on the device or the simulator? Can you post screenshots of the normal and pinkish gradients?

Comment: @Lefteris I will post screenshots as soon as I can get it to happen again. I think my 1-2% was a little off and its more like 0.1-0.2% of the time. While its an edge case, its still irritating.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance some of the times you use UIColor predefined colors? (For example greenColor)
I found those don't generate proper components.

Liviu

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't get a stack exchange notification. Sorry. I am not using UIColor predefined colors at any point, since all of my colors are coming from a server and I'm parsing them into my own colors. The data from when I parse the colors, however, is correct when I put it out to a log. Thanks for the thought, though.